# Improper de-allocation of memory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When testing my code, I consistently get errors regarding the use of delete as my class's testbed states that delete is being called on an array allocated with new[].  I have delete in my ~IntVector and two expand functions with the expand functions expanding the capacity while reallocating memory for a dynamically allocated array.

How do I use delete correctly to prevent memory leaks and resolve this error?

main file

```
#include "IntVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


IntVector::~IntVector(){
    delete[] data;
}

void IntVector::expand(){
    cap = cap * 2;
    int *data2 = data;
    data = new int[cap];
    data = data2;
    delete data2;
    delete[] data2;
}

void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount){
    cap = amount;
    int *data2 = data;
    data = new int[cap];
    data = data2;
    delete data2;
    delete[] data2;
}
```

header

```
#ifndef INTVECTOR_H
#define INTVECTOR_H

using namespace std;
class IntVector{
private:
    unsigned sz;
    unsigned cap;
    int *data;
private:
    void expand();
    void expand(unsigned amount);
};

#endif
```

Comment: My destructor is ~IntVector.

Comment: You posted a lot of code, it's very hard to miss such a small function in all that wall of code. You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: @user3314899 - Right away, a 2 line main() program can make your class fall flat on its face:  
`int main() {IntVector a(10); IntVector b = a;}`  
that's all you need -- you have a double deletion error at the end of the main().  If I added two more lines, I can reproduce a memory leak.  Read up on the rule of three, as others have suggested to overcome this error.

Comment: A double deletion error?  Edit: I'm just confused now about how to deallocate even though I've been reading some tutorials.

Comment: Look at the code I wrote in the comment.  I created an IntVector a with 10 items.  That object has a data member that points to allocated memory.  I then created another IntVector b, but it is a copy of the IntVector a.  A copy means just that -- an exact copy, meaning that the data pointer value is also copied.  On destruction, b is destroyed, calling delete[] on data.  Then a is deleted calling delete *on the same memory*.  So you have an error -- you're deleting the same memory pointed to by data twice.  That's why you need to really study and learn "the rule of three"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When allocating with `new[]` you have to use `delete[]`. Your `expand` function uses plain `delete`. It also contains some other errors (reassigning pointers, double deletion, etc.).

And where's your copy-constructor? Copy-assignment operator? You might want to read about [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: So it would be delete[] data instead of delete[] data2?

Comment: @user3314899 No, at least not to begin with. First you need to allocate the new data, then you need to copy the old data into the new data, then you need to free the old data, and lastly you need to reassign the old `data` pointer to point to the new data.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running into this issue because you're not obeying the rule of three - you need a copy constructor and an assignment operator in your class that does a deep copy.

If you do something like

```
IntVector x(IntVector(10));
```

you'll be left with a dangling pointer in `x`, because the original is de-allocated when the temporary `IntVector(10)` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the rule of there violation, you are also attempting to delete variables twice in your `expand` functions:

```
void IntVector::expand()
{
    cap = cap * 2;
    int *data2 = data;
    data = new int[cap];
    data = data2;
    delete data2; // this should not be here!
    delete[] data2; // this will be a problem now!
}
```

You can only delete data once, and if you created something with `new[]`, it needs to be deleted with `delete[]`.

Both of your expand functions should look more like:

```
// copy-swap
void IntVector::expand()
{
    IntVector tmp;
    tmp.reserve(cap * 2);
    tmp.resize(sz);
    std::copy(data, data + sz, tmp.data);
    std::swap(*this, tmp);
}
```

or

```
// raw implementation
void IntVector::expand()
{
    unsigned int newCap = cap * 2;
    int* newData = new int[newCap];
    std::copy(data, data + sz, newData);
    delete [] data;
    data = newData;
    cap = newCap;
}
```

The copy-swap version would let you reuse the other functions (destructor, copy-assignment operator) and will be more exception safe.  The raw implementation should not modify your internal data elements until the new ones are already properly created.  This prevents an exception that may be thrown in the `new` from leaving your vector in a bad state (e.g. when the `cap` is not actually your capacity).

Comment: When directly using delete[], the test harness crashes for me.  I suppose that it would be an issue with assigning to the array?

Comment: @user3314899 You'll have to show some code in order to explain what you are talking about.

Comment: void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount){
    cap = amount;
    int *data2 = new int[cap];
    data2 = data;
    delete[] data;
    *data = *data2;
}

Comment: That code is totally wrong.  It is so wrong it is hard to put a comment on it without telling you that you need to study on basic pointer usage.  For one, you're assigning the return value of new[] to data2, and then on the very next line, you replace that returned value with "data".  Why are you doing that?  That should have been obvious to you (given you're trying to write this class) that this is wrong.

Comment: @user3314899 You are assigning `data2` to a new dynamic array, then assigning it to your old `data` pointer in the next statement ... then deleting `data` in the following statement (at that point, `data2` would point to unallocated memory).  You did not follow the proper order of operations I showed in my answer.

Comment: I was trying to copy over what is in the data array to a new data array.

Comment: @user3314899 Both of the examples I show in my answer do exactly that.

Comment: When I tried the order in your example, the class's test harness would crash for me.

Comment: @user3314899 What you quoted as what you did is **not** what I show in either of the 2 methods.